# Where is addin options page in Word VSTO?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

In Outlook vsto addin to add an options page i found and used this code:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application oOutlook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        oOutlook.OptionsPagesAdd += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_OptionsPagesAddEventHandler(Application_OptionsPagesAdd);
    }
```

Where is addin options page in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing for Word Add-On. You can implement your custom window using WinForms or WPF and show it by clicking a button in the add-on's ribbon control.

Comment: Thank You Alexey. I'll use a similar looking form window in the case of word.